# How should I use the same parameter in git scm?

Tags: jenkins, mercurial, devops

I was fixing a pipeline which was written for mercurial scm and there I found an installation parameter how would I give the same parameter to the git scm.

```
checkout([$class: 'MercurialSCM', 
                credentialsId: '', 
                installation: 'HG-3.4',
                source: 'https://',
                clean: true,
                revision: branch,`branch`
                browser: [$class: 'BitBucket', url: 'https://']]) 

checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', 
                    branches: [[name: '${branch}']],                    browser: [$class: 'BitbucketWeb', repoUrl: 'https://'], 
                    extensions: [[$class: 'CleanBeforeCheckout']], 
                    userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'creds', 
                    url: 'https://']]])
```